# JQuery selectors fine point

Tags: jquery, forms, css-selectors

Was recently working on a website that involved some simple form submittals.
Rather than handle the submittals the classic, old-school html way (i.e. a form tag, with an "action=" attribute, an  button, etc.), I decided to submit the data via jquery's .ajax() method.

Handling things that way, it was necessary to *explicitly* clear the form fields, after "submittal".
Let's say the actual form looked something like this:

```
<form action="some_page.asp" id="my_form" method="post">

        <input type="checkbox" name="form_field" value="some_value" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="form_field" value="some_other_value" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="form_field" value="yet_another_value" />

        <input type="text" name="form_field" />

        <input type="hidden" name="form_field" class="MUST_NOT_CLEAR" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="form_field" class="MUST_CLEAR" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="form_field" class="MUST_CLEAR" value="" />
</form>
```

Now, even though the form has a classic "action" attribute, I'm not really using that. I'm submitting the data via JQUERY .ajax(), and therefore have to clear, or reset the form fields after "submittal".

So, the real question...how come *this code*:

```
$("#my_form").find("input:checkbox").removeAttr("checked");
$("#my_form").find("input:text").val("");
$("#my_form").find("input:hidden[class=MUST_CLEAR]").val("");
```

successfully clears all the right fields whereas *this*:

```
$("#my_form").find("input:checkbox").removeAttr("checked");
$("#my_form").find("input:text").val("");
$(".MUST_CLEAR").val("");
```

does not?

Comment: The code you say is not working actually works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/EKE5w/

Answer (score 0):

When resetting a form you could cycle through all your fields and reset them individually or you could reset a form itself:

```
$('#myform')[0].reset();
```

This may be not a direct answer to your question though but it might be helpful

**EDIT:** If you have fields that you do not want to reset you could move them out of the `<form>` as you're gathering data manually anyway. So if you leave only fields you need to reset inside the `<form>` then resetting a form is pretty easy